# Should I add a selectedUser into my ngrx store ? (Usage Question)

Tags: typescript, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a question concerning @ngrx/store usage

I have a state that looks like this =>

```
export interface MyToys{
 name: string,
 id :string,
 description,
}

export interface State extends EntityState<MyToys> {
  isLoading?: boolean;
  error?: any;
}
```

In the app, I can focus on a Toy, so select it so that all my component "synchronize" with this toy.

My question is, should this be handled by a store ?

```
export interface MyToys{
 name: string,
 id :string,
 description,
}

export interface State extends EntityState<MyToys> {
  selectedToy : MyToys;
  isLoading?: boolean;
  error?: any;
}
```

so that I can dispatch event `SELECT_TOY` or `UNSELECT_TOY`?

Or should this be handled inside a service?

I haven't find an exemple on the internet including a "currentlySelected" value inside their store. so I was wondering if it was ok.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a perfect usecase for using the store. You'll be writing more code initially but it will solve all your state management problems. No tight coupling of components, better sepearation of concerns and immutability of state.

In this case you can make a selector where your components listen for a change in the selected Toy. When a toy is selected or deslected you dispatch an action which will change the state in the store via a reducer.